# adjusting all the child div elements within the parent div

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi i am using bootstrap for designing an application, i have the entire form defined inside a container , but as i keep adding the child  inside the container div i want the parent div to expand automatically and show all the child div for example,

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="form-control"> 
  ......
  ........
  ......... 
  </div>
</div>
```

now what happens on my page is on the browser few child `<div>`s won't show up , can anyone of you tell me what attribute can i include to make the 
`<div class="container" >` to accommodate all the elements, 
i tried `overflow:auto` but this did not work.

Comment: html tags shouldnt have a space between the tag name and the opening `<` are all the tags actually like `<div>` and `</div>`?

Comment: i agree that was just typing mistake,

Comment: @user3767879 Can you give us [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/) demo?

Comment: are your `.form-control` elements floated? you may need to add any custom CSS or more HTML for us to be able to help you. if you can create a http://bootply.com or http://jsfiddle.net that'd be awesome

Comment: its a css issue or jquery, add clear before the 'form-control' class ended if its a css issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this one with jquery. I hope this will work for you.

```
$('.container').children().show();
```

Comment: I don't think the child elements are hidden - his CSS is just not working as intended.

Comment: Can you make it in Fiddle so that I can look at it.